# On Lipschitz condition and absolute continuity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> A function $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ is said to satisfy a Lipschitz condition if there exists a constant $M$, such that $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant M|x-y| ~\forall~x,y\in[0,1].
> $$

I want to show the following: If $f$ is Lipschitz, then
(i) $f$ is absolutely continuous
(ii) $f$ is of bounded variation.
(iii) $f'(x)$ exists almost everywhere on $[0,1]$ and $f(x)=\int_0^x f'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$, provided that $f(0)=0$.

*Attempt:*
(i) Let $\varepsilon \gt 0$. Choose $\delta=\varepsilon /M$. Then for any collection $\{[x_i,y_i]\}$ of non-overlapping intervals with total length $\sum |x_i-y_i|\lt \delta$, we have $$\sum|f(x_i)-f(y_i)|\lt M\sum|x_i-y_i|\lt \varepsilon.$$ Hence $f$ is absolutely continuous.

(ii) For this, can I simply use the fact that an absolutely continuous functions is of bounded variation or I would have to prove it formally?

(iii) I also know that if $f$ absolutely continuous $\implies$ $f$ is of bounded variation $\implies f'(x)$ exists a.e. and $$ f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x f'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t. $$ Thus, $f(x)=\int_0^x f'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \text{ if } f(0)=0.$

Can I use these known facts to prove (ii) and (iii)?

---

I am also asked to find a function $h(x)$ on $[0,1]$ such that $$\tag{​*​}\int_0^1 h'(x)\text{d}x\lt h(1)-h(0).$$
This is  what I did:  Let $h$ be the Cantor function is monotone increasing of $[0,1]$. $h(0)=1,~h(1)=1$. $h'=0,~\forall~x$ not in the Cantor set. Then the inequality holds.
Are there other examples where (*) holds?

Comment: Yep - your (i) is good. Apparently, your (ii) and (iii) follow from that.

Comment: (i) is indeed fine.  I would think that whether (ii) and (iii) are _allowed_ to follow automatically would be up to your professor.  If you proved that every absolutely continuous function is of bounded variation, then it would certainly seem fair game.  I would still ask your professor to be sure, however.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, your argument for (i) is perfectly fine.

---

Concerning (ii), yes, that's true, you could apply that result. On the other hand, the direct proof is straightforward:

We want to prove that
$$\tag{#}
\sup{
  \left\{
    \sum_{k=1}^n |f(a_k) - f(a_{k-1})|
     \,:\,
     0\leq a_0 \leq a_1 \leq \cdots \leq a_{n-1} \leq a_n \leq 1
    \right\}
} \lt \infty
$$
where the supremum is taken over all finite increasing sequences in $[0,1]$. Finiteness follows from the Lipschitz condition $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq M\cdot|x-y|$ because for a finite increasing sequence $0\leq a_0 \leq a_1 \leq \cdots \leq a_{n-1} \leq a_n \leq 1$ we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n |f(a_k) - f(a_{k-1})| \leq \sum_{k=1}^n\phantom{|} M \cdot |a_k - a_{k-1}| \leq M
$$
because $|a_k-a_{k-1}| = a_{k}-a_{k-1}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k-a_{k-1}) = a_n -a_0 \leq 1 - 0 = 1$. This proves that the supremum in $(\#)$ is in fact bounded by $M \lt \infty$.

This seems a bit easier than making the detour via absolute continuity (you'll notice that I hardly did anything else than what you did in your proof for (i), and that's why I gave the fully detailed argument).

Compare this with the proof of the fact that absolute continuity of a function $f$ implies that it is of bounded variation (which isn't much more difficult, but somewhat more fiddly, I think).

---

Now for (iii) I don't think that it is intended that you do this by hand, as a direct and detailed proof of this involves a considerable amount of work. So what you do is almost certainly the intention of this exercise.

Be a little careful, though: you say

> I also know that if $f$ absolutely continuous $\implies$ $f$ is f bounded variation $\implies f'(x)$ exists a.e. and $$ f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^1 f'(x)\text{d}x. $$ Thus, $f(x)=\int_0^1 f'(x)\text{d}x~~~\text{if}~~f(0)=0.$

The second implication you write here is *not* true: bounded variation alone doesn't give that $f(x) = f(0) + \int_{0}^x f'(t)\,dt$ — note that there are two typos here as well:

1. the upper bound of the integral should be $x$ instead of $1$ and
2. your equality $f(x) = f(0) + \int_{0}^1 f'(x)\,dx$ involves $x$ with two different meanings: on the left hand side you have some point $x \in [0,1]$ and on the right hand side you have $x$ as a “dummy variable” for integration.

To see that the implication that bounded variation of $f$ doesn't imply that $f(x) = f(0) + \int_{0}^x f'(t)\,dt$, just notice that the Cantor function $h$ is monotone, hence of bounded variation, but $\int_{0}^x h(t)\,dt = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

However, I think that you meant to say that $f$ absolutely continuous implies $f(x) = f(0) + \int_{0}^x f(t)\,dt$ without interrupting by "$f$ has bounded variation", and then the rest of the argument here is fine too.

---

To get other (trivial examples) for your last question you can of course take any continuously differentiable (or even only absolutely continuous) function $g$ and add $h$ to it. Genuine examples not involving the Cantor function or simple variations of it are a bit cumbersome to come up with, so I think you solved that exercise satisfactorily, too.

When looking up something else, I recently found this [nice and careful write-up](http://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/SeniorProjectArchive/2009/grady.pdf) by Noella Grady, which is about the present and many related matters.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. For (iii), what I wanted to say was that If $f$ is absolutely continuous, the $f'$ exists a.e. and $f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^x f'(t)~\text{d}t $.

Comment: I was pretty sure that this was what you meant, that's why I didn't expand on what *is* correct. Just be careful with such formulations, because it is hard to tell such slips from genuine misconceptions (when correcting homework or an exam).

Comment: Thanks also for pointing out the typos. I'm most grateful.

Answer (score 6):

For the counterexample, since you are not requiring differentibility everywhere in $[0,1]$, you can always use a step function like:
$$h(x):=\begin{cases} 0 &\text{, if } 0\leq x<1/2 \\ 1&\text{, if } 1/2\leq x\leq 1\; .\end{cases}$$
In fact function $h$ is differentiable a.e. with $h^\prime=0$ a.e., hence:
$$0=\int_0^1 h^\prime (x)\ \text{d} x< h(1)-h(0)=1\; .$$