# If $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ is $C^1$, must $f$ be absolutely continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ has continuous derivative. Can we say that $f$ is absolutely continuous?

Comment: Here is exactly [the same problem](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F85009%2Fon-lipschitz-condition-and-absolute-continuity&ei=8mYpUc6nO9PlqAHS7YAw&usg=AFQjCNE1UOm8SAsrfFvopbxMh4AKuEdK9w).

Comment: possible duplicate of [On Lipschitz condition and absolute continuity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85009/on-lipschitz-condition-and-absolute-continuity)

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Not exactly the same. In this problem one has to show first that $C^1$ implies Lipschitz.

Answer (score 5):

Is the derivative continuous?

If so, is $[0,1]$ compact?

Would this imply that $f$ has a bounded derivative?

If so, might this imply that $f$ is Lipschitz?

Comment: Be carefull, if $C^1 [0,1]$ is defined as continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$ the derivate only exists on $(0,1)$, so $\sqrt{x}$ is not lipschitz.

Comment: Excellent point :) In this case the argument needs a little massage for 0 and 1. The functions $$f_n:= f((1-1/n)x+1/n))$$ look very nice.

Comment: Hm. I think that for most people $C^1[0,1]$ is the space of functions which can be extended to a $C^1$ function on an open set containing $[0,1]$. It is a matter of definition, though, and the OP should probably tell us what is his.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can say that f is absolutely continuous, since [0,1] is compact, and f is continuos (is $C^1$ therefore is $C^0$).

Affirmation: Every continuous function $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is absolutely continuos.

Proof:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \forall x \in [a,b], \exists\; \delta_x > 0;\\
y \in I_x\cap[a,b]=(x - \delta_x, x+\delta_x)\cap[a,b] \rightarrow \!|f(y) - f(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

It's easy to see that $[a,b] \subset \bigcup_{x\in[a,b]}I_x$. Since [a,b] is a compact there exists a finite number of $I_x$ that covers [a,b] (Borel-Lebesgue theorem). Therefore, $[a,b] \subset \bigcup_{\lambda = 1}^{n}I_\lambda$. $\delta = \min(\delta_{\lambda_1}, ..., \delta_{\lambda_n}) \rightarrow \forall x, y \in [a,b]; |y-x| < \frac{\delta}{2}. x, x_\lambda\in I_\lambda,$ for some $0<\lambda\leq n$, where $|x-x_\lambda| < \frac{\delta}{2} \rightarrow |f(x) - f(x_\lambda)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$

$$|y - x_\lambda| \leq |y-x| + |x - x_\lambda| \leq \frac{\delta}{2} + \frac{\delta}{2} = \delta \rightarrow |f(y)-f(x)| \leq |f(y) - f(x_\lambda)| + |f(x_\lambda) - f(x)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$

Sorry for the poor formating. Hope that helped.

Comment: This only shows uniform continuity, not absolute continuity.  The affirmation you state is actually false: the cantor function is continuous everywhere on $[0,1]$, but not absolutely continuous.