# Prove that the set $\mathcal{O} $ is absolutely continuous.

Tags: proof-writing

If $\mathcal{O}$ denote the collection of real-valued functions defined on $[0,1]$ that map every set of measure zero to a set of measure 0. Prove that the set $\mathcal{O} $ is absolutely continuous. could anyone give me a hint for the proof?

Comment: This may be me being dense, but do you mean show that every function in $\mathcal{O}$ is absolutely continuous?

Comment: yes I mean showing that every function in $\mathcal{O}$ ..... @Keen-ameteur

Comment: It seems that what you wrote is that every function in $\mathcal{O}$ satisfies the Luzin property: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luzin_N_property. It says there that it is a necessary but not sufficient condition for absolute continuity. It also appears in the wikipedia page on absolute continuity.

Comment: but it says also this "Also, if a function f on the interval [a,b] is continuous, is of bounded variation and has the Luzin N property, then it is absolutely continuous." @Keen-ameteur

Comment: @Keen-ameteur are my functions continuous? are they of BV ?

Comment: By what you wrote it seems that you defined $\mathcal{O}$, to be the set of real valued functions satisfying the Luzin property. So by what you quoted it seems that no. Also see this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499101/example-of-a-function-that-has-the-luzin-n-property-and-is-not-absolutely-cont

Comment: So you mean that this proof can not be done @Keen-ameteur .... correct?

Comment: what about proving that every Lipschitz function belongs to the set mentioned above  .....how can we prove this? (in the link of the question I provided above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll write this here since we are starting to have a lengthy discussion in the comment section which we are not supposed to do.

As I said earlier, this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luzin_N_property) shows that the property you wrote is the Luzin property, and it also states that in the page on [absolute continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Properties) that it is part of the sufficient and necessary condition for absolute continuity:

> $f: [a,b] → \mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous if and only if it is continuous, is of bounded variation and has the Luzin N property.

This [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499101/example-of-a-function-that-has-the-luzin-n-property-and-is-not-absolutely-cont) gives examples that it does not imply absolute continuity, and finally this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85009/on-lipschitz-condition-and-absolute-continuity) shows how to show that Lipschitz functions are absolutely continuous.

To avoid spamming the comment section, I will edit this answer instead.